# How I can use the Intranetwebapplication in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want use asp.net mvc 3 and use intranet application but I don't have this option :( How I get the intranet application

[image]

and how I get mvc4 or it don't work on vs2010?

Comment: mvc 4 does work in VS 2010, go to http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 and the install section gives you the options .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge, you just develop a web aplication and then usually
it's important to have structure where customers vain access a server-capable network traffic